# SpriteKit level editor scene size for iPhone game?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

This question has been asked before but I've never found the answer I was looking for.

The story goes like this: I wanted to make a universal game, I had the scene size in the level editor set to the largest size, 2048x1536.

Everything was going fine, until I implemented iAd which started to give me problems with the scene and the way it resized itself to fit on all the devices. When I opened the ad on a device which wasn't 2048 pixels wide the ad stretched the scene and other strange behaviour.

So now I want to make an iPhone version and an iPad version of my game and my question is: which size do I set the scene in the level editor? Do I set it to be the one of the biggest device? or the smallest? 
And how do I position the sprites in the scene?

If it can be useful, mine is not a tile based game, I don't have a 'world' or a camera, what's on the scene is what you see in the game.

This is my GameViewController:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

    var adBannerView: ADBannerView!

    func loadAds() {

        adBannerView = ADBannerView(frame: view.frame)
        adBannerView.delegate = self
        adBannerView.hidden = true
        view.addSubview(adBannerView)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let scene = MainMenuScene.unarchiveFromFile("MainMenuScene") as? MainMenuScene {

            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = false
            skView.showsDrawCount = false
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            skView.presentScene(scene)

            loadAds()
        }
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeLeft, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeRight]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        print("Ad about to load")
    }

    func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

        adBannerView.hidden = false
        print("Displaying the Ad")
    }

    func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        print("Close the Ad")
    }

    func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {

        print("Leave the application to the Ad")
        return true
    }

    func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {

        adBannerView.hidden = true
        print("Ad is not available")
    }
}
```

For the ad I've tried all of the scaleModes and the one who makes the ad work right (not perfectly though) both on iPhone and iPad is .Fill but then my sprites are resized in a way I don't like. And I'm using the Scene Editor so changing the images or the positions of the sprites in code doesn't seem like the most efficient way.

Comment: You will need to show how you are adding the iAd.  The scene will resize (depending on settings) and I'm guessing you'll need to find out what scaling has been performed in order to adjust the iAd view.

Comment: What is your scale setting for your scene?  I can see a few problems with this approach,  like you are designing for 4:3, but iphones are 16:9  and you are not accounting for that.  or the iAd is changing your aspect to a different ratio other than the 2, causing even more distortion

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you set up object constraints, you could possibly try setting the

```
SKSceneScaleMode
```

To

```
.ResizeFill
```

Then adding the following variables

```
var screenSize = UIScreen.mainscreen().bounds
var screenWidth = screenSize.width
var screenHeight = screenSize.height
```

And when adding your nodes and other objects position and size them based on screenWidth and screenSize